# Regex format in java for specified characters

Tags: java, regex

I need regex format of allowing '#','-' and alphanumeric values and should not allow any other value. I have tried the regex `"^[A-Za-z0-9#-]"`. it allowing all special characters not at beginging but at other places.

Comment: You should probably read a regex tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9#-]+$
```

Your regex: `^[A-Za-z0-9#-]` is only checking for these character at the line start. You need to use quantifier `+` with anchor `$`.